# Citation 'et al.' in overleaf

Tags: citing, ieeetran, overleaf

I have written a document with Overleaf for IEEE Transactions. I have almost completed it but I would like to cite as 'Richard et al. [1]' with et al in italics.

Right now I have been writing it manually which of course is not in italics. I am already done with bibliography. Do I need to change the command i.e. `\cite{}` or to add some package.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
Richard et al. \cite{CRreliability} gives a detailed study about the reliability of wireless networks.
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{CRreliability}
A. Richard, B.C. Christopher, E. Williams, "Reliability of wireless networks", \textit{ABC Communications \& Networks IEEE}, vol. XX, no. 2, pp. XXX-XXX, 20XX. 
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is it fine if I just use `\textit{et al.}`, I just tried it and it helped.